# Tensorflow Linear Regression model returns huge cost values then inf values and stops with many Nan values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, nan

Thank you for your interest in this question.
I have been struggling with this error for hours, and I have read all the comments in the forums I came across but in vain.
I am trying to train dataset with a Linear Regression. The example first worked great and everything was good until I changed the random data generated with actual data. The data I am using is read from a file (I used numpy functions to extract the data into a numpy array, so I have a function that returns a numpy array with 939 lines, each has 11 features). So I have this line:

```
all_xs = fn.read_from_file_to_array(filename)
```

where fn is a module's name and read_from_file_to_array is a function that generates a numpy array from data written in a file.
I have checked the type of all_xs and it's a numpy array.
I kept the Ys random (the results from which the model should learn) and for every X (aka for every line) I have y, then I add every y to the list all_ys with

```
all_ys.append(y)
```

and finally

```
all_ys = np.transpose([all_ys])
```

gives me a numpy array (the code works fine on a console, outside of all the tensorflow code, I made sure every line of my code works fine before changing things into the example with tensorflow).
Then the model is trained and I am using this cost function:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_-y))
```

What I have understood from many forums is when the Logistic Regression is used, a problem of 0log(0) can occur and adding a small constant fixes the problem, however, I don't know if a similar problem applies to Linear Regression as well, I have also tried adding a small constant but with no luck, I have changed the learning rate (tried both small and bigger values) but in vain.
I really don't know what to do, the example used to work fine with random data generated, all I did was using my own numpy array (which I am sure IS a numpy array, not a list or any other type), the moment I changed this, nothing would work again.
I am really confused and I have no idea what I should try, I also have no time to lose on trying random modifications in the code (which I find is not even logic) because my internship period is about to end and I have to give back my work soon.
Also, I couldn't post the whole code here because I have signed a confidentiality contract if you know what I mean, really sorry about that. 
The error that I get is

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: HistogramSummary
 [[Node: HistogramSummary = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](HistogramSummary/tag, W/read)]]
```

which from what I understood doesn't come from the tensorboard itself (it was working fine before the changes) but it comes from the Nan values given to the graph.

Comment: Do you need to use TensorFlow for such basic model? I recommend to use sklearn's LogisticRegression it is much easier to use.

Comment: yeah my boss suggested Tensorflow so I have no choice, also, it is rather better to begin with basic models while learning new things (I forgot to mention that I am new to machine learning and Tensorflow)

Comment: I found this jupyter example https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/2_BasicModels/logistic_regression.ipynb You should be able to adopt it.

Comment: thank you! I will check it out and get back to you if everything works. This is logistic regression though, while my example which used to work is Linear regression (which is the model I need) and I think messing up with the logistic regression code will produce more errors

Comment: afaik your model doesn't use logs (you use squared loss, not log loss aka cross entropy). your error suggests that it's the summary writer that has a problem. have you tried commenting it out and just printing stuff. also, can you check if `np.all(np.is_finite(name_of_input_numpy_array))` to make sure that there is no problem with the input array itself / with the way it's read

Comment: Hello Julius, thank you for your feedback! Actually I have solved the problem. It turned out that the learning rate wasn't low enough (actually it was low and it worked for other examples, maybe because the data changed so I had to make it even smaller)

Comment: TensorFlow (at HEAD) now has a builtin debugger called tfdbg. It should give you some insight to where the nans come from in your model. Please take a look at the official tutorial: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/debugger/index.md

Comment: Thank you for our help scai, however, I am no longer working on Tensorflow as I have already finished my internship project and I have moved to another one ^^ I hope your answer will help someone else who'd face the same problem!  Best regards!